# RSpec test if method is called on module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm Using RSpec (2.14) in Rails and am trying to test if a method is called on a module, and I'm not finding any of the traditional methods available.

```
module TestModule
  self.method_to_test
  end
end
```

I'm aware that one needs to call `stubs` instead of `stub` on modules, however I can't seem to figure out how to test a `have_received`, `receive`, or `should_receive` method.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I know is:

```
module TestModule
  self.method_to_test
  end
end
```

And you spec test_module_spec.rb:

```
describe "TestModule" do
  let(:dummy_class) do
    Class.new do
      include TestModule

      def to_s
        "Dummy class"
      end
    end
  end

  context 'class methods' do
    subject { dummy_class }

    it { should respond_to(:method_to_test)}
    it { should be_a(TestModule) }
    its (:to_s) { should eq("Dummy class") }
  end

end
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, Surya.  I ended up using the Flexmock gem, which adds an `expects` method to classes and modules (i.e. TestModule.expects(:method_to_test)) and you can add .once, .with(parameters), etc.